# Maven : No tests were executed

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, cucumber

I am abe to run my Junit runner for Cucumber using maven command line. My runner file is located in /src/java/test/Runners/ directory. Following is the command that I am using:

```
mvn surefire:test -Dtest=OneTest.java
```

Following is my Cucumber Test Runner

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"summary","pretty","com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:", "json:target/cucumber-report/TestResult.json"},
    monochrome = false,
    features = "src/test/resources/features/SampleTestFeatures/SampleTest.feature",
    glue="Steps")
public class OneTest{
}
```

I am able to run the tests via command line but after the tests have passed, the build fails giving the following error:

```
1 Scenarios (1 passed)
6 Steps (6 passed)
0m30,603s

[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 31.923 s - in Runners.OneTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  43.123 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-22T15:12:11+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test     (default-test) on project test: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Following is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<!--<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> &lt;!&ndash; lookup parent from repository &ndash;&gt;
</parent>-->

<groupId>tony</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.26</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>2.11.2</log4j.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Binding for Log4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Log4j API and Core implementation required for binding -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apiguardian/apiguardian-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
        <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.28.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Web driver manager dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Start - Following dependencies are for XRAY export functionalities -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End - Dependencies are for XRAY export functionalities -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.29</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.codearte.jfairy/jfairy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.codearte.jfairy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfairy</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have tried different versions of surefire plugin but in vain.  The test passes all the time even if I launch it directly from the Test Runner as well as via maven command but via maven the build is always marked as failed. If anyone could point me where this error is coming from, it'd be of great help.

**UPDATE:**
I know the following is not a smart option but replacing the maven surefire plugin like the following fixed my issue without modifying any other dependecy in the pom

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>both</parallel>
                    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

It works for Junit Runner Classes but not for TestNG. My tests are now passed and the maven build succeeds as well. If anyone has more generic way of implementing the same for both TestNG and Junit Runner classes, would be absolutely brilliant.

Comment: You are using a pre-release version of surefire `3.0.0-M4`. Have you tried the latest regular release?

Comment: Yes. I have tried with all versions from 2.19.1 till 3.0.0.M4. From what I read, 2.22.0 was a stable version. But it does not help as well. Just to understand the root cause, I created a sample project with just one feature, step definition and a runner with the same POM.xml. Still the same error. So, I think there is some issue in my pom file which I just can't figure out.

Comment: @automaticien Can you share the sample project using github?

Comment: @automaticien I am getting 404 error. You may have to change permissions.

Comment: @Ramu I just changed the project to public. you should have access

Comment: @automaticien See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you are seeing the error is due to the way you are passing the `test` argument.

As per the [Maven Surefire's official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html), you need to pass test class name.
So change your command line argument to `-Dtest=OneTest`

**Edit: Ignore the above answer.**

After looking at your pom.xml, one thing is certain that some older version of `cucumber-core` dependencies were included and also `testng` dependencies were included. I excluded those dependencies and it's working fine now.

Also, one of the plugin (com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:) is not compatible with cucumber version > 4.2.0. See this [blog](http://grasshopper.tech/824/). So I removed that plugin.

**OneTest.java**

```
package Runners;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"summary","pretty","json:target/cucumber-report/TestResult.json"},
        monochrome = false,
        features = "src/test/resources/features/test.feature",
        glue="Steps")
public class OneTest{
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample_project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.26</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>2.11.2</log4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Binding for Log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j API and Core implementation required for binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apiguardian/apiguardian-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
            <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.28.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Web driver manager dependency -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start - Following dependencies are for XRAY export functionalities -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End - Dependencies are for XRAY export functionalities -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.codearte.jfairy/jfairy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.codearte.jfairy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfairy</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Sorry. I looked at the documentation again, and as per the documentation, even if you provide the extension, the extension will be stripped. So the way you passed (with extension) should not cause this.

Comment: Yes. I even tried mvn -Dtest=OneTest.java test command. Does not work as well. Same error as always.

Comment: thanks for your help but I cannot remove testng dependencies from the project as I have old tests that are dependent on them. I had read somewhere having both Junit and TestNG dependencies causes such issues but I was earlier able to build with both of them in my pom. As far as extent adapter is concerned, I have to use it as it generates our test report. Appreciate your help anyways.